# boost python explicit typecast needed

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have hybrid system (c++, boost python).
In my c++ code there is very simple hierarchy

```
class Base{...}
class A : public Base{...}
class B : public Base{...}
```

2 more business (on c++)  methods

```
smart_ptr<Base> factory() //this produce instances of A and B
void consumer(smart_ptr<A>& a) //this consumes instance of A
```

In python code I create instance of A with the `factory` and try to call consumer method:

```
v = factory() #I'm pretty sure that it is A instance
consumer(v)
```

Absolutely reasonable I've got exception:

> Python argument types in consumer(Base) did not match to C++ signature: consumer(class A{lvalue})

It happens because no way how to tell Boost that some conversion efforts should be there.

Is there some way how to specify dynamic casting behavior?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, smart_ptr<A> (which is expected by consumer()) is not a derived class of smart_ptr<Base>, so a dynamic_cast wouldn't be enough, or you need a dynamic_pointer_cast...

Comment: @GHL most declaration of smart pointers have a lot operations that provides desired semantic for example in boost: `template<class T, class U>
    shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast(shared_ptr<U> const & r)` or `template<class T> ... template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y * p)`. So my mention of 'dynamic' wider then reference to `dynamic_cast` operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to `boost::shared_ptr`, Boost.Python generally provides the desired functionality.  In this particular case, there is no need to explicitly provide custom `to_python` converters as long as the module declaration defines that `Base` is held by `boost::shared_ptr<Base>`, and Boost.Python is told that `A` inherits from `Base`.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<Base, boost::shared_ptr<Base>, 
         boost::noncopyable>("Base", no_init);
  class_<A, bases<Base>,
         boost::noncopyable>("A", no_init);
  def("factory",  &factory);
  def("consumer", &consumer);
}
```

Boost.Python does not currently support custom lvalue converters, as it requires changes to the core library.  Therefore, the `consumer` function either needs accept the `boost:shared_ptr<A>` by value or by const-reference.  Either of the following signatures should work:

```
void consumer(boost::shared_ptr<A> a)
void consumer(const boost::shared_ptr<A>& a)
```

---

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

class A
  : public Base
{
public:
  A(int value) : value_(value) {}
  int value() { return value_; };
private:
  int value_;
};

boost::shared_ptr<Base> factory()
{
  return boost::make_shared<A>(42);
}

void consumer(const boost::shared_ptr<A>& a)
{
  std::cout << "The value of object is " << a->value() << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<Base, boost::shared_ptr<Base>, 
         boost::noncopyable>("Base", no_init);
  class_<A, bases<Base>,
         boost::noncopyable>("A", no_init);
  def("factory",  &factory);
  def("consumer", &consumer);
}
```

And the usage:

```
>>> from example import *
>>> x = factory()
>>> type(x)
<class 'example.A'>
>>> consumer(x)
The value of object is 42
>>>
```

Since the module declaration specified that `Base` was a base-class for `A`, Boost.Python was able to resolves the type returned from `factory()` to `example.A`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. You have to declare your own "from-python" converter. It is vaguely explained on the boost.python documentation (look at [this answer in the FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#custom_string)), but you will find tutorials around the net, like [this one](http://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/how-to-write-boost-python-converters/). Here is a complete example, based on your initial input that does what you want:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class A: public Base {
  public:
    A(int v): _value(v) {}
    int _value;
};

boost::shared_ptr<Base> factory() {
  return boost::make_shared<A>(27);
}

void consumer(boost::shared_ptr<A> a) {
  std::cout << "The value of object is " << a->_value << std::endl;
}

struct a_from_base {

  typedef typename boost::shared_ptr<A> container_type;

  // Registers the converter for boost.python
  a_from_base() {
    boost::python::converter::registry::push_back(&convertible, &construct,
        boost::python::type_id<container_type>());
  }

  // Determines convertibility: checks if a random 
  // object is convertible to boost::shared_ptr<A>
  static void* convertible(PyObject* ptr) {
    boost::python::object object(boost::python::handle<>(boost::python::borrowed(ptr)));
    boost::python::extract<boost::shared_ptr<Base> > checker(object);
    if (checker.check()) { //is Base
      boost::shared_ptr<Base> base = checker();
      if (boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(base)) return ptr; //is A
    }
    return 0; //is not A
  }

  // Runs the conversion (here we know the input object *is* convertible)
  static void construct(PyObject* ptr, boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data) {

    // This is some memory allocation black-magic that is necessary for bp
    void* storage = ((boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_storage<container_type>*)data)->storage.bytes;
    new (storage) container_type();
    data->convertible = storage;
    container_type& result = *((container_type*)storage); //< your object

    // The same as above, but this time we set the provided memory
    boost::python::object object(boost::python::handle<>(boost::python::borrowed(ptr)));
    boost::shared_ptr<Base> base = boost::python::extract<boost::shared_ptr<Base> >(object);
    result = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(base);
  }

};

// Your boost python module: compile it and run your test
// You should get "The value of object is 27".
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(convertible) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<Base, boost::shared_ptr<Base>, boost::noncopyable>("Base", no_init);
  class_<A, boost::shared_ptr<A>, bases<Base>, boost::noncopyable>("A", no_init);
  a_from_base();
  def("factory", &factory);
  def("consumer", &consumer);
}
```

You can extend this example by writing another from-python converter for your class `B` or, just template that structure above to accommodate all children of `Base`.

Comment: well in pure form you sample works! But I found dramatic mistake in my example - just make consumer instead of `void consumer(smart_ptr<A> a)` as `void consumer(smart_ptr<A>& a)` - one ampersand crashes everything. Any idea? (actually I'm editing my example)

Comment: Sure, the problem is that from-python converters can only operate on const T& or T. There is currently no way in Boost.Python to handle non-const references as explained in [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2008-May/013263.html).    So, your only option in this case is to manually write a converter. I'll post another answer with that. **Also note that the answer by twsansbury is more elegant than mine**. I forgot that all should be covered for `boost::shared_ptr<>` already - w/o the need to write specialised from-python converters.

Comment: just FYI, actually this example works well even without converter at all. (I'll post standalone comment on your next answer).

Comment: That is what I said in my previous comment, referring to the answer by twsansbury - it won't work as you expect though for non-const references.

Answer (score 3):

As it is posed, your problem cannot be solved using automatic (or manual) from-python converters as explained [in this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2008-May/013263.html). You will need to patch it through, emulating the dynamic type behaviour so it works as you expect from Python. I assume that, since you are passing a non-const reference, you will need to change it inside the `consumer()` method.

Here is a fully working example. The C++ plumbings need to know all possible derivations of `Base` or a `TypeError` is raised in Python. Hands-on:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

class Base {
  public:
    Base(int value) : value_(value) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    int value() const { return value_; };
    void value(int value) { value_ = value; }
  private:
    int value_;
};

class A : public Base {
  public:
    A(int value): Base(value) {}
};

class B : public Base {
  public:
    B(int value): Base(value) {}
};

class C : public Base {
  public:
    C(int value): Base(value) {}
};

boost::shared_ptr<Base> factory(boost::python::str choose) {
  if (choose == "a") return boost::make_shared<A>(1);
  else if (choose == "b") return boost::make_shared<B>(10);
  else return boost::make_shared<C>(100);
}

void consumer_a(boost::shared_ptr<A>& a) {
  std::cout << "The value of object was " << a->value() << std::endl;
  a = boost::make_shared<A>(a->value()+1);
  std::cout << "The new value of object is " << a->value() << std::endl;
}

void consumer_b(boost::shared_ptr<B>& b) {
  std::cout << "The value of object is " << b->value() << std::endl;
  b = boost::make_shared<B>(b->value()+1);
  std::cout << "The new value of object is " << b->value() << std::endl;
}

void consumer_python(boost::shared_ptr<Base>& base) {
  //try the first one
  boost::shared_ptr<A> a = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(base);
  if (a) {
    consumer_a(a);
    base = a; ///< don't forget the assignment here
    return;
  }

  //try the second one
  boost::shared_ptr<B> b = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(base);
  if (b) {
    consumer_b(b);
    base = b; ///< don't forget the assignment here
    return;
  }

  //we leave C uncovered to see what happens ;-)

  //if you get here, you can raise an exception for python
  PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "Input type is neither A or B");
  throw boost::python::error_already_set();
}

//notice you don't even need to declare a binding for A, B or C
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<Base, boost::shared_ptr<Base>, boost::noncopyable>("Base", no_init);
  def("factory",  &factory);
  def("consumer", &consumer_python);
}
```

After compilation, you can run this script and see it working:

```
import example
print "Creating object of type A..."
a = example.factory("a")
print "Consuming A twice..."
example.consumer(a)
example.consumer(a)

print "Creating object of type B..."
b = example.factory("b")
print "Consuming B twice..."
example.consumer(b)
example.consumer(b)

print "Creating object of type C..."
c = example.factory("c")
print "Trying to consume (uncovered) C..."
example.consumer(c)
```

The output should be something like:

```
Creating object of type A...
Consuming A twice...
The value of object was 1
The new value of object is 2
The value of object was 2
The new value of object is 3
Creating object of type B...
Consuming B twice...
The value of object is 10
The new value of object is 11
The value of object is 11
The new value of object is 12
Creating object of type C...
Trying to consume (uncovered) C...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    example.consumer(c)
TypeError: Input type is neither A or B
```

Comment: great example of workaround, thank you, anyway +1 for each answer. Unfortunately this is not applicable for me - because boost-to-python declaration is auto-generated for my code and I can't freely change declaration. That is why the way like converters more applicable, following this I need create adapter on c++ that is finally facade for desired methods without ampersand